# Find first occurrence of the biggest element smaller than target in array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I'd like to find the index of the **first occurrence** of the biggest element in an array smaller than a target value `n`. I'll make an example to make it clearer. Let's say I have this numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 1])
```

If I set the target `n = 0.5`, than I'd like to obtain the lowest index between the two `0.4`'s, which are both the highest elements in the array smaller then `n`. So, in this case the returned index should be `2`. If I set `n = 0.9`, then the returned index should be `4`, which is the lowest index of the `0.7`'s, and so on...

Of course I could do this with a `for` loop, but I am looking to a pythonic solution which is fast and readable. What I tried so far are approaches based on `np.argmin(np.unique(A)<n) -1`, but they don't work as I want. For example:

```
np.argmin(np.unique(A)<0.5) - 1
```

returns correctly `2`, but

```
np.argmin(np.unique(A)<0.9) - 1
```

returns `3`, because it is not counting the two occurrences of `0.4` that have been "compacted" by the `np.unique()`. Does anybody have an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A one-liner with `np.nanargmax` + `np.where` -

```
In [175]: np.nanargmax(np.where(A<n,A,np.nan))
Out[175]: 2
```

Another one if `n` is positive -

```
In [180]: (A*(A<n)).argmax()
Out[180]: 2
```

Another with `np.flatnonzero` -

```
In [114]: idx = np.flatnonzero(A<n)

In [115]: idx[A[idx].argmax()]
Out[115]: 2
```

Another with more usage of masks to be more memory-efficient -

```
def argmax_lesser_than_thresh(a, n):
    m = A<n
    m2 = m.copy()
    s = np.ones(m.sum(), dtype=bool)
    s[A[m].argmax()] = False
    m2[m] = s
    return (m2!=m).argmax()
```

As discussed in the comments, if the input array is a sorted one, we can use `np.searchsorted` too, like so -

```
(A==A[max(0,np.searchsorted(A,n)-1)]).argmax()
```

Or even the following with additional check required if `n` is same as `A[0]` -

```
A[:np.searchsorted(A,n)].argmax()
```

Comment: Doesn't this calculate A - n < 0  for **all** elements? I guess you could stop after you find the first one that meets this condition.

Comment: @Anteino OP doesn't want to loop as stated in the question. I am not looping. And argmax does the finding of the first match in a vectorized manner. Hence, it's used that way.

Comment: Right, disregard then ;)

Comment: Wow, thanks! So many ideas here :). Actually, your second method is very similar to one I just came up with: `A[A<n].argmax()`. Thanks again for all the nice suggestions!

Comment: @Tropilio `A[A<n].argmax()` won't work if say A[0] is a big number `(>n)`, like `0.6`.

Comment: Yep, you are right. However, my `A` array will always be sorted from smallest to biggest (it is a cumulative sum), so that should do the trick. Between all the methods you suggested, which one you think is the fastest? Do you think using a `for` loop could be faster?

Comment: @Tropilio You can use a loop if you think the occurence of the threshold would be close to the start, as we would be breaking off when iterating. Or use `numba` library to iterate efficienctly. Added one more with `np.searchsorted` to make use of sorted nature.